# Missing metrics for "kubelet_volume_*" in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, amazon-eks

I setup latest https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus/ in an AWS EKS cluster in which I'm using the Amazon EBS CSI driver for persistent volume claims, but I don't see any **"kubelet_volume_*"** metrics being available in prometheus.

According to https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/issues/223 the metrics are not yet supported by EBS CSI, in which case what could I use to monitor the volumes free disk space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support was added in version 0.9.0 of the ebs csi driver with this PR https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/pull/677

Answer (score 0):

The EBS CSI metrics need to be exported from AWS cloudwatch to prometheus. There are several tools like [YACE](https://github.com/ivx/yet-another-cloudwatch-exporter) for example that can do that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately as far as I could find AWS cloudwatch does not report internal, system-level metrics such as disk usage on the volumes, because CloudWatch collects metrics via a hypervisor.